# Clicking an image underneath a div

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

I have a plugin which creates a lens over an image, but cannot make the image clickable when underneath the lens.

I created this on jsfiddle to help illustrate the problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/F9GT5/2/

I need to be able to make the image clickable to then perform a set of actions.

I have seen it done on some sites such as this here: http://www.starplugins.com/cloudzoom

```
 $('#myCloudZoom').bind('click',function(){       // Bind a click event to a Cloud Zoom instance.
        var cloudZoom = $(this).data('CloudZoom');   // On click, get the Cloud Zoom object,
        cloudZoom.closeZoom();                       // Close the zoom window (from 2.1 rev 1211291557)
        $.fancybox.open(cloudZoom.getGalleryList()); // and pass Cloud Zoom's image list to Fancy Box.
        return false;
    });
```

This problem has been driving me nuts for a couple of days now, with the cloudzoom plugin, it seems like they are clicking through the lens to the image below. But as shown in the code above, the click even is bound to the image, but when you inspect element, you get the lens over the top of the image.

Has anyone any ideas on how to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your plugin, store the selector for the image in the div somehow:

```
//Inside the plugin, creating the lens; add attribute for image
$("<div>").data('image', this)
//Then bind a click event to the div to trigger a click on the image:
   .click(function () {
      $(this).data('image').trigger('click');
   });
```

Comment: cool... This has solved it for me... fantastic!

in the click function i had to do it slightly different. 
$(this).trigger('click');

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood your problem, but I think that what you want is to add the "click" event to your "lens" div:

```
$(".lens").click(function(){
alert("click lens");    
});
```

Comment: no, because there may be multiple instances of a lens over the image on the page

you can see on the cloudzoom site, that when you click on the image it does a popup, but you bind the click to the image, not the lens. i hope that makes sense?

Comment: so, what you want is that the event only gets triggered if the "lens" div is overlapping your image?

Comment: well basically if the users clicks over the image... but the lens is obviously in the way. as in the cloudzoom example - for user to just reference the image and bind a click to it